# disable mobaxterm ^M windows carriage returns on unix session text streams

Tags: windows, unix, sed, cygwin

I have mobaxterm installed on a windows machine. I then connect over ssh to a unix machine. Then I run something like `sed 's/$/end/' my_infile.txt > my_outfile.txt`, but `cat my_outfile.txt` shows a bunch of windows carriage returns (`^M`) in it that mess up the output.

Why did this happen and is there a configuration setting to fix it?

Comment: also may be worth noting that I am using tcsh

Answer (score 0):

Remove all CR symbols, then append `end` to the end of each line:

```
sed -e 's/\r//g' -e 's/$/end/' my_infile.txt > my_outfile.txt
```